# SQL Loop for a simple query

Tags: sql, loops

I am new to SQL and need to loop a query for 20 times and put on a summary table output.  What's the most efficient way of doing that?

```
From lower = 1 to lower = 20

select distinct middle, sum(case when signups>0 then 1 else 0 end) signup_uv 
from HULU.dbo.Jan_core_converter where  lower =1 

group by middle having middle <=20 order by middle
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: SQL operates on set based data best.  Looping to return 20 records isn't the best method to get 20 records.  if your table has a field called Lower, then why not just add that as a where clause `where lower between 1 and 20`?  Additionally provide sample data, table structure and expected results to help clarify your question, I'm sure we can help but not without context.

Comment: If you want to loop a query may be you have to use a While loop

Comment: Do you use MS SQL Server? What version?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of this on top of my head. This should avoid looping atleast. Working along these lines should be a good starting point :

```
SELECT         distinct con.middle,
               SUM(CASE
                    WHEN con.signups > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) signup_uv 
FROM           HULU.dbo.Jan_core_converter con
WHERE          con.lower BETWEEN 1 AND 20
GROUP BY       con.middle
ORDER BY       con.middle
```

Hope this helps!!!